# Saving a greyscale image as a bitmap file converts to indexed colours

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-spaces, grayscale

I'm trying to save an image as a Greyscale bitmap file in Photoshop but it keeps changing to Indexed colours. This also causes the image to become really dark. I am trying to change the files of a game and it is very important that the image stays in a greyscale format.

Comment: What format are you saving the images as?

Comment: i'm saving it as a bitmap

Comment: That's the issue. BMP files are indexed. In Photoshop, I believe they may even be by default indexed down to 2 colors unless you choose a specific pallet for it to use. If you must have BMP files then you're going to have to create a custom grayscale pallet for it to index to. (all that said, .bmp is a somewhat antiquated file format. Are you sure the developer can't use other file formats such as PNG?)

Comment: Thank you very much, a guy who was helping me told me to save it as greyscale when it is meant to be index. Thank you for helping me figure that out.

Comment: @DA01 you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DA01 writes in the comments above:

> BMP files are indexed. In Photoshop, I believe they may even be by default indexed down to 2 colors unless you choose a specific pallet for it to use. If you must have BMP files then you're going to have to create a custom grayscale pallet for it to index to. (all that said, .bmp is a somewhat antiquated file format. Are you sure the developer can't use other file formats such as PNG?)

This turned out to be the issue. A guy who was helping me told me to save the image as greyscale when it should have been indexed. Thank you for helping me figure that out.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51716)

Comment: To expand on @Wrzlprmft's comment, if the "answer" that helped you is actually a comment, it's perfectly fine to post your own answer restating it, and accept that. But you should still phrase it as an answer to your question (even though you're writing it yourself), not as "thanks for the answer."